# Как из строки вытащить дату

Tags: java, android

я хочу сделать приложение в котором:

Пользователь нажимает кнопку -> Появляется Google RecognizeIntent > Пользователь говорит фразу в любом формате к примеру "Я хочу завтра купить книгу","Мне 12 ноября надо в кино","Разбуди в 10 утра" -> Приложение выполняет различные действия по его словам, например назначает напоминание на дату

Я пробовал по ключевым словам искать, пробовал через matcher find "\d+", но все не то. В Гугл Ассистент есть эта функция, но там открывает сразу приложения гугл

Как я могу реализовать?